# How to use SLEEP, WAKE and POWER keys as media keys (VolumeUp , Volume Down etc) in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, xmodmap, media-buttons

I have an usb keyboard with SLEEP, WAKE and POWER keys but no media keys. In Ubuntu 12.04 i used xmodmap to remap this keys as XF86AudioMute, XF86AudioLowerVolume and XF86AudioRaiseVolume.
This is how it was done:
**.Xmodmap** in user's home directory:

```
keycode 124 = XF86AudioRaiseVolume
keycode 150 = XF86AudioMute
keycode 151 = XF86AudioLowerVolume`
```

**.xinitrc** in user's home directory:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

As far as i remember it was enough to use SLEEP, WAKE an POWER keys as media keys (Mute, Volume Down, Volume Up).

Now i have fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 and this approach yields no result.

**xev** recognizes new mappings, but these keys still do not work as media keys.
Example of **xev** output for POWER key:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 78, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x25d, subw 0x0, time 3802034, (1198,451), root:(1228,573),
    state 0x10, keycode 124 (keysym 0x1008ff13, XF86AudioRaiseVolume), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 123
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I have tried different usb keyboard which does have media keys and they work as expected.

Example of **xev** output for "Volume Up" key on keyboard with media keys:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 79, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x25d, subw 0x0, time 4268348, (810,191), root:(961,347),
    state 0x10, keycode 123 (keysym 0x1008ff13, XF86AudioRaiseVolume), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Clearly i don't understand something here and i'm asking for help.

**P.S.** I have disabled default functionality of SLEEP, WAKE and POWER keys by setting

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power.active = false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power.button-hibernate = nothing
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power.button-power = nothing
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power.button-sleep = nothing
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power.button-suspend = nothing
```

through dconf-editor.

**P.P.S.** My first move was to use Ubuntu's System settings. While it seems to have the ability to set other keys as media keys, it doesn't work, at least on my system.